# How to map a client ID to an IPv4 address?

Tags: bash

I have a bash script that creates 1024 clients. I have to allocate IPv4 addresses from a given subnet to those clients accordingly. The challenge is how to map the client ID to a IPv4 address.

```
COUNTER=0
for ip in 172.16.10{0..4}.{0..255} 
do
  COUNTER=$((COUNTER+1))
  FILE_NUMBER="${COUNTER}"
  CLIENT_IPV4="${ip}"
  echo "###Client ${COUNTER}###
        Address = ${CLIENT_IPV4}/32" >"$HOME/${FILE_NUMBER}.conf"
done
```

While this seems ok at first, later on I need to know that Client 500, corresponds to the IP address `172.16.101.243`. Is there any clever way to do that?

I came up with this solution, but I'm not sure if this is a good one:

```
function map_client_to_ipv4() {
  val=$(($1/256))
  mod=$(($1%256))
  ret_val=172.16.10${val}.$((mod-1))
}

map_client_to_ipv4 500
echo $ret_val
```

Comment: FYI, `function funcname() {` merges the POSIX sh syntax `funcname() {` and the legacy ksh syntax `function funcname {` in a way that's incompatible with *both* POSIX sh and legacy ksh. See https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/obsolete

Comment: So I should remove `function` in this case?

Comment: BTW `172.16.10{0..4}.{0..255}` is 1280 IPs, you want `172.16.10{0..3}.{0..255}`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach seems good enough to me. I would just print the result instead of defining a global variable that holds the result:

```bash
map_client_to_ipv4() {
    set "$(($1-1))"
    printf '%s\n' "172.16.10$(($1/256)).$(($1%256))"
}

map_client_to_ipv4 500
```

```
172.16.101.243
```

If you're using `bash` and you need to call `map_client_to_ipv4` several times in your script then it might be advantageous to build an array that maps each client ID to its IP address, so that you can access the IPs directly:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

client_to_ipv4=( _ 172.16.10{0..4}.{0..255} )
unset client_to_ipv4[0] # remove the dummy first element

echo "${client_to_ipv4[500]}"
echo "${client_to_ipv4[800]}"
```

```
172.16.101.243
172.16.103.31
```

In any case, it's surely a good idea to do some validations on the client ID before using it:

```bash
map_client_to_ipv4() {
    case $1 in ( '' | 0* | *[^0-9]* ) return 1;; esac
    set "$(($1-1))"
    printf '%s\n' "172.16.10$(($1/256)).$(($1%256))"
}

map_client_to_ipv4 -0 || echo 'something went wrong' 1>&2
```

```
something went wrong
```

Comment: I found this approach better, as I don't have to load all clients in an array everytime I need the mapping. Less CPU bound this way. I also found a bug with `printf '%s\n' "172.16.10$(($1/256)).$(($1%256-1))"`. The `-1` creates a problem for client id 0 and client id 256. Since it ends up like: `172.16.100.-1` and `172.16.101.-1` respectively.  Removing `-1` makes it perfect, it's ok to start from 0. I hope there aren't any other edge cases that we may have missed. Thanks

Comment: @Houman I fixed the code for when the clients IDs that start from `1`, but you're right, it's easier to start the numbering from `0`.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to use an array.

```
counter=0;
arr=();

for ip in 172.16.10{0..4}.{0..255}; do
  counter=$((counter+1));
  arr[$counter]="$ip";
done

echo "${arr[500]}"
```

Output:

```
172.16.101.243
```